# Numpy slicing: all entries except these ones

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array a. I would like to select a random sample of this array as a test and training set for cross-validation. As a training set, I use slicing by selecting the entries idx. Is there a way to select a compliment of these entries? i.e. all entries that are NOT in idx.

```
# N: size of numpy array a.
idx = random.sample(np.arange(N),N/10) # select random sample
train(a[idx]) # train on this random sample
test(a[ NOT idx]) # test on the rest.
```

How to call the rest of the entries in a compact way for the last line?
Thanks.

Comment: `test(a[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(N), idx)])` works too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make `idx` a boolean array, then you can select the complement with `~idx`:

```
import numpy as np

N = len(a)
idx = np.zeros(N, dtype='bool')
idx[np.random.choice(np.arange(N), size=N/10, replace=False)] = True
train(a[idx]) # train on this random sample
test(a[~idx]) # test on the rest.
```